# Rename Caffe layers through pycaffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

Is there a simple way of renaming layers in a [caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe) network by using the *pycaffe* interface?

I have looked through the [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) example, but I cannot find an example of what I need.

For example, I would like to load a trained Caffe model and change the name of `conv1` layer and its corresponding blob to `new-conv1`.

Comment: see: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_net_spec.py

Comment: Also the following question/answer may be what you need.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423309/how-reconstruct-the-caffe-net-by-using-pycaffe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know a direct way to do it, but here is a workaround:

Given a pretrained Caffe model `my_model.caffemodel` and its net architecture `net.prototxt`. Make a copy of `net.prototxt` (say `net_new.prototxt`), and change the name of `conv1` layer to `new-conv1` (you can change the names of `bottom` and `top` if you want).

```
import caffe
net_old = caffe.Net('net.prototxt','my_model.caffemodel',caffe.TEST)
net_new = caffe.Net('net_new.prototxt','my_model.caffemodel',caffe.TEST)
net_new.params['new-conv1'][0].data[...] = net_old.params['conv1'][0].data[...]  #copy filter across 2 nets
net_new.params['new-conv1'][1].data[...] = net_old.params['conv1'][1].data[...]  #copy bias
net_new.save('my_model_new.caffemodel')
```